# How to store tilt/rotation and crop information in metadata?

Tags: metadata, rotation, cropping

Is there a standard or defacto-standard to store tilt (slight rotation for horizon correction like e.g. 2 degree) or crop information in a photo's metadata (EXIF, IPTC, ...), so it

a) does not compromise the raw quality of the image, but

b) can be re-applied or changed later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**XMP**](http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/index.html) is what you're looking for, now an ISO standard it is no longer vendor specific to Adobe.

XMP files are where Adobe Camera Raw stores its data on crop and rotation options for example.  Plus, XMP is usually implemented as a 'sidecar' file so absolutely no changes to the source file are made, allowing for unlimited changes without loss of data.

The 'standard' metadata systems like EXIF & IPTC do not store that information (so far as I'm aware.)

`CropTop`, `CropLeft`, `CropBottom`, `CropRight`, `CropAngle` are some of the properties are used by Adobe Camera Raw Settings to store crop information and can be found in the namespace `http://ns.adobe.com/camera-raw-settings/1.0` (usually mapped to `crs`.)

**References**

- Adobe XMP Developer Center (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html)
- ExifTool documentation (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html#crs)
- Sample XMP with a crop (http://pastebin.com/qNcvM4Yb)

Comment: What fields exactly within XMP would cover tilt and crop?

Comment: The first result from a Bing search gave me `CropTop` `CropLeft` `CropTop` `CropLeft` `CropAngle` in the namespace http://ns.adobe.com/camera-raw-settings/1.0/ (usually mapped to `crs`)

Comment: Your Bing-fu seems to be better than my Google-fu :) Could you please add this info to the answer, then I'll accept it.